# How do I calculate the total resistance of this potentiometer circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance, circuit-design

[image]

Can somebody explain to me how to calculate the total resistance of the circuit in the picture?

I do not understand how to deal with the potentiometer and the red line. Does the current flow over \$R_{2.1}\$, bypassing \$R_{2.2}\$ and going on to \$R_3\$ and \$R_{\text{B}}\$? So would it be \$R_{\text{total}} = R_{2.1} + (R_{\text{B}} \parallel R_3)\$?

Comment: Which 2 points do you wish to know the resistance?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the resistance at the two wires, yes, R2.2 is shorted out (in parallel with zero).
It's completely bypassed.

Therefore total resistance (when switch is closed) is:

Rt = R2.1 + R3//RB               [ // symbol for 'in parallel']
Rt = R2.1 + (R3*RB/(R3+RB))

If you want the resistance across UB, then just ignore R2.1 and work out R3//RB.

Answer (score 0):

If the red line is a conductor, and in some variable resistance circuits there is often a wire from the wiper to one end of the pot, then yes, your description is correct.

Unfortunately you don't have your equation represented correctly, as the parallel combination of *R3* and *RB* is **(RB*R3)/(RB+R3)**. This is often written informally as **RB||R3**, with || pronounced 'in parallel with'. You may therefore have a typo in your Text/Mathjax, having intended to write RB||R3 rather than RB/R3.

Another way to think of it, staying with 'proper' resistance calculations, is that the resistance between *R3* and the wiper is **R2.2||Rwire**, which is around zero because Rwire is roughly zero.